# How do I add up the loaded value from a textfile with the new inputed value in the Jtextfield

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, io, jframe

[image]

> When I press the load button it displays the values from the reload.txt

```
   public class VotingSystem extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private final JTextField[] textFields;

/**
 * Creates new form VotingSystem
 */
public VotingSystem() {
initComponents();

textFields = new JTextField[12];

textFields[0] = koontf;
textFields[1] = baamtf;
textFields[2] = sachitf;
textFields[3] = fakertf;
textFields[4] = phonsekaltf;
textFields[5] = lauretf;
textFields[6] = yeontf;
textFields[7] = aguerotf;
textFields[8] = agnistf;
textFields[9] = lokitf;
textFields[10] = lawliettf;
textFields[11] = ryuzakitf;
} private void loadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

int line = 0;
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("reload.txt"))){
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        textFields[line++].setText(scanner.nextLine());
        if(line == textFields.length){
            break;
        }
    }
}catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
    Logger.getLogger(VotingSystem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
koontf.requestFocus();  // you can only call request focus on one element at a time (it does not make sense to call it on all textfields

}                                    

private void baamtfActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

[image]

> When I  press vote It shoud add up but instead it returns to 1. Any way I can make it add up to the imported value???Below is the code for the Vote Jbutton.

```
     int pick1 = 0, pick2 = 0,pick3 = 0, pick4 = 0,pick5 = 0, pick6 = 0, pick7 = 0, pick8 = 0, pick9 = 0, pick10 = 0, pick11 = 0, pick12 = 0;
private void voteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (koonchk.isSelected()){
        pick1++;
    koontf.setText(Integer.toString(pick1));
    }
    else if (baamchk.isSelected()){
        pick2++;
    baamtf.setText(Integer.toString(pick2));
    }
    if(sachichk.isSelected()){
        pick3++;
    sachitf.setText(Integer.toString(pick3));
    } 
    else if (fakerchk.isSelected()){
        pick4++;
    fakertf.setText(Integer.toString(pick4));
    }
    if (phonsekalchk.isSelected()){
        pick5++;
    phonsekaltf.setText(Integer.toString(pick5));
    }
    else if (laurechk.isSelected()){
        pick6++;
    lauretf.setText(Integer.toString(pick6));
    }
    if (yeonchk.isSelected()){
        pick7++;
    yeontf.setText(Integer.toString(pick7));
    }
    else if (aguerochk.isSelected()){
        pick8++;
    aguerotf.setText(Integer.toString(pick8));
    }
    else if (agnischk.isSelected()){
        pick9++;
    agnistf.setText(Integer.toString(pick9));
    }
    if (lokichk.isSelected()){
        pick10++;
    lokitf.setText(Integer.toString(pick10));
    }
    else if (lawlietchk.isSelected()){
        pick11++;
    lawliettf.setText(Integer.toString(pick11));
    }
    else if (ryuzakichk.isSelected()){
        pick12++;
    ryuzakitf.setText(Integer.toString(pick12));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you are initialising all the variables as

```
int pick1 = 0, pick2 = 0,pick3 = 0, pick4 = 0,pick5 = 0, pick6 = 0, pick7 = 0, pick8 = 0, pick9 = 0, pick10 = 0, pick11 = 0, pick12 = 0;
```

So the previous values of text that you had loaded are lost. I would suggest that you initialise the variables as:

```
int pick1 = Integer.parseInt(textFields[1].getText());
int pick2 = Integer.parseInt(textFields[2].getText());
.
.
.
//And so on.
```

This will ensure that the previous number in the text field stays where it is.

A still better solution would be you could declare an Integer array of variables as `pick` with size of 12. Like:

```
int[] pick = new int[12];
```

Then declare a method that is going to update the text fields with the value of `pick` like:

```
public void updateTextFields(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        textFields[i].setText(String.valueOf(pick[i])); //corrected the code
    }
}
```

Now in your reading file method instead of

```
    textFields[line++].setText(scanner.nextLine());
```

use

```
    pick[i++] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

and at last line of the method simply call the previously declared `updateTextFields()`.

Also in the method to vote, remove all the code for `textField.setText()`. and in the last line simply call the method `upadateTextFields()`. What I mean by this is:

```
private void voteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    if (koonchk.isSelected()){
        pick1++; //Change to pick[1]++
//    koontf.setText(Integer.toString(pick1)); remove
    }
    else if (baamchk.isSelected()){
        pick2++; //change to pick[2]++
//    baamtf.setText(Integer.toString(pick2)); remove
    }
    if(sachichk.isSelected()){
        pick3++; //change to pick[3]++
//    sachitf.setText(Integer.toString(pick3)); remove
    } 
    else if (fakerchk.isSelected()){
        pick4++; //Change to pick[4]++
//    fakertf.setText(Integer.toString(pick4)); remove
    }
    if (phonsekalchk.isSelected()){
        pick5++; //Change to pick[5]++
//    phonsekaltf.setText(Integer.toString(pick5)); remove
    }
    else if (laurechk.isSelected()){
        pick6++; //Change to pick[6]++
//    lauretf.setText(Integer.toString(pick6)); remove
    }
    if (yeonchk.isSelected()){
        pick7++; //Change to pick[7]++
//    yeontf.setText(Integer.toString(pick7)); remove
    }
    else if (aguerochk.isSelected()){
        pick8++; //Change to pick[8]++
//    aguerotf.setText(Integer.toString(pick8)); remove
    }
    else if (agnischk.isSelected()){
        pick9++; //Change to pick[9]++
    //agnistf.setText(Integer.toString(pick9)); remove
    }
    if (lokichk.isSelected()){
        pick10++; //Change to pick[10]++
    //lokitf.setText(Integer.toString(pick10)); remove
    }
    else if (lawlietchk.isSelected()){
        pick11++; //Change to pick[11]++
    //lawliettf.setText(Integer.toString(pick11)); remove
    }
    else if (ryuzakichk.isSelected()){
        pick12++; //Change to pick[12]++
    //ryuzakitf.setText(Integer.toString(pick12)); remove
    }
    updateTextFields(); //Add this new line.
}
```

Comment: It show an error "variable Textfields might not have been initialized.

Comment: should it be int pic1 = Integer.parseInt(textFields[0].getText()); ?

Comment: @JericMarquez sorry its a typo I have corrected it.

Comment: It seems that I have a problem with changing the names of the declared variables because of the results.` private void resultActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(pick1 > pick2 ){
        message.append("The New President is Koon!\n");
        }
        else if(pick2 > pick1){
        message.append("The New President is Baam!\n");
        }`

Comment: @JericMarquez.where ever you have `pick1` replace with `pick[1]` and so on in your whole code and it would solve your problem

Comment: I have a Result Jbutton that was using the pick1 and pick2 to compare each other and printout a message to the results text area

Comment: and where do I place the code `public void updateTextFields(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        textFields[i].setText(pick[i]);
    }
}

Comment: its a new method it should be placed inside the class but outside any method.

Comment: @JericMarquez you should declare it in the class. and the code like `lokitf.setText(Integer.toString(pick10));` or code lines with `setText` in the method `voteActionPerformed` are to be removed.

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble but could you please reformat the codes I used as an example??? I'm really confused right now.

Comment: should I also remove `int line = 0;` and`if(line == textFields.length){
                break;
            }`?

Comment: and the code block for the`    public void updateTextFields(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        textFields[i].setText(pick[i]);
    }
    }` has an error that says 'int cannot be converted to string'

Comment: @JericMarquez I have suggested the changes requied

Comment: it still has an error `    public void updateTextFields(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        textFields[i].setText(pick[i]);
    }` int cannot be converted to string and should I still use this? `int pick1 = Integer.parseInt(textFields[1].getText());
int pick2 = Integer.parseInt(textFields[2].getText());`
    }`

Comment: @JericMarquez use `String.valueOf` as I have corrected above.